# .net winforms listbox vertical scroll

Tags: winforms, listbox

I have a winforms listbox control with vertical scroll,when I scroll it with mouse wheel it works perfectly but when I try scrolling with mouse click on vertical scroll it closes how to handle that events.

I didn't find a event in listbox with vertical scroll mouse click .can someone suggest why it is not working properly .

Although if I create a sample project of winforms with listbox vertical scroll works in both the cases.

Comment: You have some other event in form that fires which closes form

Comment: thank you, I have identified the problem by identifying the event which is triggering the close of list box.